# Session Timeout & Sliding Timeout

Tags: session, session-variables, session-cookies, session-state

I am implementing Identityserver where sliding expiration value is set at client side. So is it secure?

Does asp.net session timeout work in similar way? i.e. client side comparison?

Just need theory about whether session timeout is client side thing or server side thing.

What exactly happens when session timeout. Cookie clear or any server value clear?

Answer (score 0):

`Sliding expiration` means that each time the session is accessed it will reset the timer back to 20 minutes again.
Also, by default `sliding expiration` is used so you don't need to write any code.

If the user does not access the session for the `timeout` period then the session will expire. If the user accesses the session at(for instance) 3:01 then the session will expire at 3:21. If the user accesses the session at 3:10 then the session will then expire at 3:30. It is always 20 minutes after the user **last accessed** the session (that is the meaning of sliding expiration). If the user does not access the session in that 20 minutes then the session will expire.

Hope the answer gets you a glimpse of sliding expiration...